# How do I call an ArrayList from a different class?

Tags: java, arraylist

In the method getNumberOfMoves() I want to call the stack 'to' and 'from' that is created in the main method, because I want to calculate the number of times an element is moved between the stacks.

I want to check if the stack 'to' is empty, in that case 0 number of moves have been made, and if it is full, then a certain amount of moves have been done (2^n)-1. But I'm having trouble calling the stack in question, no variable is accepted, nor 'to' or 'myStack'.

```
public class StackPlay {

    public static long getNumberOfMoves() {
        //This is were I get problems!
    }

    public static void move(myStack from, myStack to, myStack help, int n) {
        help.push(from.pop());
        to.push(help.pop());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 3;
        myStack from = new myStack(size);
        myStack to = new myStack();
        myStack help = new myStack();
        System.out.println("Start state");
        System.out.println("   From: " + from);
        System.out.println("   To:   " + to);
        System.out.println("   Help: " + help);
        System.out.println("   Number of moves: " + getNumberOfMoves());
        move(from, to, help, size);
        System.out.println("End state");
        System.out.println("   From: " + from);
        System.out.println("   To:   " + to);
        System.out.println("   Help: " + help);
        System.out.println("   Number of moves: " + getNumberOfMoves());
    }
}
```

Below is the class that creates the stacks:

```
public class myStack {

    private ArrayList<Integer> specStack;

    public myStack() {
        specStack = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public myStack(int n) {
        this.specStack = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            specStack.add(i, n-i);
        }
    }

    public void push(int x) { 
        if (specStack.size() == 0) {
            specStack.add(x);
        } else if (x > specStack.get(specStack.size() -1)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Number too high");
        } else {
            specStack.add(x);
        }
    }

    public int pop() {
        if (specStack.size() == 0) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Empty stack");
        } else {
            int length = specStack.size() -1;
            int topEl = specStack.get(length);
            specStack.remove(length);
            return topEl;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        String arrList = "[";
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < specStack.size(); i++) { 
            if (i == specStack.size() -1) {
                arrList = arrList + specStack.get(i);
            } else {
                arrList = arrList + specStack.get(i) + ",";
            }
        }
        arrList = arrList + "]";
        return arrList;
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I understand, to access the two objects 'to' and 'from'  inside getNumberOfMoves method, you should either declare the objects as global variables, or pass them as parameters to the function getNumberOfMoves.

Comment: Why don't you simply calculate the moves inside `move` method? Change its return type to int, calculate moves and return the result.
Another way, as @BlackPearl correctly suggests, could be to declare a global variable, maintain return type of `move` method as it is and increment the value of the new global variable.

Comment: Also, I would suggest renaming myStack to MyStack, so as to follow standard Java naming conventions.

Comment: Alright. So I should declare them within the getNumberOfMoves method?

Comment: Not declare. Pass as arguments, like `getNumberOfMoves(myStack from, myStack to, myStack help)`

Comment: What I want in the getNumberOfMoves method is to get 'size', right? And specifically the size of the 'to' stack to determine whether 0 moves occurred (to is empty) or 2^size -1 (to is full) occurred. My problem is that I can't reach this variable in getNumberOfMoves.